# How to list all media files in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to know how to extract all media files present in windows phone 7 in my own media player.

How to list all media files programatically in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Looking up how to use `MediaLibrary` would be a start... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the `MediaLibrary` class. Here's an example of how to retrieve all the songs in the media library and play the first one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx